# Keypress is not registered sometimes

Tags: key-bindings, evil, keystrokes

I'm using evil mode and I've bound `C-g` to switch to normal state:

```lisp
:bind
(:map evil-insert-state-map
      ("C-g" . evil-normal-state))

(:map evil-visual-state-map
      ("C-g" . evil-exit-visual-state))
```

But sometimes when I type quickly and press `C-g`, say, to exit visual state, nothing happens. I tried to debug this behaviour - it's all okay with commands, Emacs just doesn't register keypress event

Running `view-lossage` command (`C-h l`) shows that `C-g` hasn't been pressed

It's also all okay with my keyboard - I don't observe this behaviour in Vim (which feels less sluggish in general though)

It looks like it has something to do with how Emacs processes key events

Any help is appreciated as now I don't have ideas on how to further debug this problem or even how to google for solution

Comment: It looks like setting `gc-cons-threshold` variable to a high value (1 Gb) helps  - I've installed `gcmh` package to manage GC